getting {"error":"Handshake was canceled."} on asp.net core signalr on live server windows iis on local working fine
I installed websocket package enabled it but issue still there. this is simple code that is created f
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace SignalRChat.Hubs
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }
    }
}


How do you configure to enable the websocket? Please follow the document to provide some details  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-8.0 . The behavior represents a server issue so to narrow down the issue , some points to check. What is the application pool setting? Is Web.config enabled?

The previous link is mainly about local environment issue , you could try these ways to check the issue. 1. SignalR provides log and diagnostics configurations https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-8.0 , you can get the logs and share to us but please delete the sensitive information. 2. Or you could handle the issue through the OnConnectedAsync method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-8.0#handle-events-for-a-connection .

@FengzhiZhou still issue there
